# Merge dataframe and string

Tags: python, string, dataframe, mean

I am trying to use a data frame to regroup different kind of data.

I have a data frame with 3 columns :

- one that I define and the index (used a groupby command)
- one that regroups a parameter, say 'valeur1', for which I want a mean for these that have the same index (used a mean command after the group by)
- the last column contains strings. There is only 1 string for each index but some cell might contain nan.

I am trying to get in the end a dataframe with the mean for 1 parameter depending on the index as well as the string that goes with the index (nan in the string column are not important). Here is a picture with an example or what I am trying to get : [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp1rL.png) . Main issue is that dataframe.mean does not work with string

The code I used so far is pretty basic :

```
dataRaw=pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
data=dataRaw.groupby(index)
databis=data.mean();
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group by multiple columns:

```
databis = dataRaw.groupby(['index', 'String']).mean()
```